# How to use nested include in sequelize with where clause?

Tags: postgresql, include, sequelize.js, postgresql-9.5, sequelize-cli

I would like to fetch the results of specified college, 
Exam table has `startDate`, `EndDate`, `noOfStudents` and `collage_id`.
Students table has `examId` & `subject`
result table has `studentId`, `score` and `grade`.
I have tried this below query it returns null for students and none for the exam also it has been returning all data which is present in result DB, I need only belongs to a specified college so any suggestion here, please

```
results.find({
   include: [{
      model: models.students,
      include: [{
         model: models.exam,
         as: 'exam',
         where:{collage_id:id}
      }],
      as: 'students'
   }]
});

Output:{
   "id": 1,
   "student_id":2,
   "score": 88,
   "grade" : B,
   "created_at": "2018-11-14T13:38:25.377Z",
   "updated_at": "2018-11-14T13:38:25.377Z",
   "students": null
}

Expected Output:{
   "id": 1,
   "student_id":2,
   "score": 88,
   "grade" : B,
   "created_at": "2018-11-14T13:38:25.377Z",
   "updated_at": "2018-11-14T13:38:25.377Z",
   "students": {
      "examId": 2
      "subject":
   },exam:{
      "startDate":Date, 
      "EndDate":date, 
      "noOfStudents" : 100
      "collage_id": 1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see few confusions in your question.

1. According to your question in your `Students table` I can see you **only have** columns `examId` & `subject`. so how do you link `Results` table with `Students` table.

To link `Results` table with `Students` table your student table should be `Students(id / studentId,examId,subject)`

and the association (link) `results.belongsTo(students,{foreignKey:'id / studentId'})`

After doing these this only you can say,

```
results.find({
   include: [{
      model: models.students,
   }]
});
```

2. second problem I can see is you want **an association** (link) between your `Students` table and your `Exams` table, but your `Exams` table **you only have columns** `startDate`, `EndDate`, `noOfStudents` and `collage_id`. So where does the association here? How do you link **student** to **exam**.

I think the column `noOfStudents` means Number of students. If you mean the id of the student.

You have to have an association `Student.hasMany(Exam,{foreignKey:'noOfStudents'})`

After doing these to you will be able to query,

```
results.find({
   include: [{
      model: models.students,
      include: [{
         model: models.exam,
         where:{collage_id:id}
      }]
   }]
});
```

I'm not sure about the keyword `as` since I am also new to this little bit. as far as I know you have to use the keyword `as` in your associations before you use it your query though I'm not sure about it.

And also try to trace you query for this (console) and see what it generates. =)